# DeserializeObject<T> returns object with null/default values

Tags: c#, json.net

In the event that I try to deserialize the following json

```
{ "error": "Invalid order request" }
```

I would expect an exception to be thrown when deserializing it to a class of a completely different structure

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderResponse>(errorJson);
```

but instead it returns an object with default/null values

```
response.orderNumber == 0;           // true
response.resultingOrders == null;    // true
```

My OrderResponse class is below:

```
public class OrderResponse
{
    public long orderNumber;
    public List<Order> resultingOrders;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public OrderResponse(long orderNumber, List<Order> resultingOrders)
    {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.resultingOrders = resultingOrders;
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public long orderId
    public decimal amount;
    public string type;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Order(long orderId, decimal amount, string type)
    {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.type; = type;
    }
}
```

I want the deserialization step to throw an exception or return a null object. I thought adding the [JsonConstructor] attributes would resolve the issue, but no dice here.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to create my own JsonConverter or can I modify some other de/serializer settings?

Comment: `{ "error": "Invalid order request" }` this json is only an object.What's your expect?

Comment: @D-Shih "I want the deserialization step to throw an exception or return a null object"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To throw an exception, you will have to change the default Serialization Settings. By default, Json.NET ignores when a member of the Json is missing in the class:

> `MissingMemberHandling` – By default this property is set to Ignore
>   which means that if the Json has a property that doesn’t exist on the
>   target object it just gets ignored. Setting this to Error will cause
>   an exception to be thrown if the json contains members that don’t
>   exist on the target object type.

The code should be something like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderResponse>(errorJson, serializerSettings);
```